# Convert Float Date to YYYY-MM-DD Format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Date column with float values and would like to convert to YYYY-MM-DD

```
Date
43411.74786 
43381.63381 
43339.3885
```

I've tried a few methods from the other threads but still can't solve it.

> 1. df['Date'] = 
>      pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y/%m/%d').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
>
> This changes the year to 1970.
>
> 2. df['Modified'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Modified'], unit='s')
>
> This changes the year to 1970.
>
> 3. df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d.0')
>
> I get an error message: **time data '43411' does not match format '%Y%m%d.0' (match).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date,unit='d',origin='1900-01-01')
Out[364]: 
0   2018-11-09 17:56:55.104
1   2018-10-10 15:12:41.184
2   2018-08-29 09:19:26.400
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: How do I remove the timestamp "17:56:55.104" and leave just the dates?

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df.Date,unit='d',origin='1900-01-01').dt.date @sufyanahmad

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, let me know if this works for you.

```
x['Date_new']=pd.to_datetime(x.Date, unit='d', origin='1900-01-01').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
x
```

output

```
       Date      Date_new
0   43411.74786  2018-11-09
1   43381.63381  2018-10-10
2   43339.38850  2018-08-29
```